# How to write a python function that adds all arguments?

Tags: python, function, arguments, addition

I'd like to write a python function which adds all its arguments, using `+` operator. Number of arguments are not specified:

```
def my_func(*args):
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + ...
```

How do I do it?

Best Regards

Comment: When using `*args` then `args` is a list of all arguments passed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: A tuple, to be precise.

Comment: If this is a followup to [How to find the list in a list of lists whose sum of elements is the greatest?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11519787) then you need to specify what kind of input this function will take. Your question, as it now stands, will not get you any more helpful answers than what I already gave you there.

Comment: But it doesn't matter what the input is, it should just add arguments using + operator.

Comment: Well, then what's the problem with Python's built-in `sum`? That's precisely what it does.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what kind of input you have and what kind of output you expect? For integers, sum is unbeatable, but clearly you have different input.

Comment: @alwbtc I added another solution to my answer which does not use sum and so does what you want. But it would be helpfull if you could say what's wrong with `sum` in the first place.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use the [sum](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function

```
>>> def my_func(*args):
...     return sum(args)
...
>>> my_func(1,2,3,4)
10
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

I don't know why you want to avoid sum, but [here we go](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
>>> def my_func(*args):
...   return reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), args)
...
>>> my_func(1,2,3,4)
10
>>>
```

Instead of the `lambda` you could also use [operator.add](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.add).

---

**Edit2:**

I had a look at your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519787/how-to-find-the-list-in-a-list-of-lists-whose-sum-of-elements-is-the-greatest) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520087/how-to-use-a-custom-function-in-maxx-key-custom-function-function/), and it seems your problem is using `sum` as the `key` parameter for `max` when using a custom class. I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521976/142637) your question and provided a way to use your class with `sum` in my answer.

Comment: But I don't want to use `sum` function.

Comment: @alwbtc - why don't you want to?

Comment: @eumiro perhaps he wants to use the `+` operator for cases other than numbers.

Comment: @HenryGomersall In this case he should simply add the `__radd__` method to his class.

Comment: I assume you could reduce with operator.add instead of (lambda (x, y): x + y) in the second case, correct? (Seems correct.)

Comment: @CorporalTouchy Yes, correct. I also noticed that in my answer already.

Comment: Second answer looks elegant.
I'm using this in django orm for getting sum of multiple fields at one time.

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
def my_func(*args):
    my_sum = 0
    for i in args:
        my_sum += i
    return my_sum
```

If you don't want to use the `+=` operator, then

```
my_sum = my_sum + i
```

Comment: This is generalised to make it different to `sum()` by replacing `my_sum = 0` with `my_sum = args[0]` and the loop to be `for i in args[1:]`. This now works on any list of objects with a sensible `__add__` method.

Comment: You could also leave the method as it is and implement a sensible  `__radd__` method in your class.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus If it's not one's own class, then it's likely to be easier to change the function (e.g. strings).

Answer (score 1):

If you definitely won't be using `sum`, then something like:

```
def func(*args, default=None):
    from operator import add
    try:
        return reduce(add, args)
    except TypeError as e:
        return default
```

or `functools.reduce` in Py3

Answer (score -1):

```
def sumall(*args):
   sum_ = 0
   for num in args:
       sum_ += num
   return sum_

print(sumall(1,5,7))
```

The output is `13`.